# How to inherit static methods from base class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, static

I'm trying to achieve some basic OOP in JavaScript with the prototype way of inheritance. However, I find no way to inherit static members (methods) from the base class.

We can simulate the basic class model by using prototype:

```
SomeClass = function(){
    var private_members;

    this.public_method = function(){
        //some instance stuff..
    };
};

Class.static_method = function(){
    //some static stuff;
};

//Inheritance
SubClass = function(){ //sub-class definition };
SubClass.prototype = new Class();
```

However, `SubClass` doesn't inherit `static_method` from `Class`.

Comment: Mootools is the answer to your problems! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class BaseClass {
    static baseMethod () {
        console.log("Hello from baseMethod");
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

Object.assign(MyClass, BaseClass);
```

They key is `Object.assign` which should be everyone's new best friend. You can now call any base method from `BaseClass` using `MyClass` as follows:

```
MyClass.baseMethod();
```

You can see this live and in action on [this pen](http://codepen.io/donavon/pen/NrddNz?editors=0011).

Enjoy!

Comment: This answer does what I want, the key is the line of code using "Object.assign()"

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf(MyClass, BaseClass)` will avoid clobbering any overriden static methods.

Comment: This answer is a strange fit for the question. While it is a viable solution, the question was asked years before the `class` expression was supported by most browsers and the sample code was clearly using the function prototype for implementing inheritance.

Comment: It [works](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpdyOx?editors=0011) in ES6 [without the assignment](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3300-static-methods-are-inherited-when-using-es6-extends-syntax-in-javascript-and-node-js.htm).

Comment: As @chocolateboy mentioned, this answer is wrong. `Object.assign` isn't needed, you can verify this by running `MyClass.baseMethod()` without it

Answer (score 20):

In the classical (OO) inheritance pattern, the static methods do not actually get inherited down. Therefore if you have a static method, why not just call: `SuperClass.static_method()` whenever you need it, no need for JavaScript to keep extra references or copies of the same method.

You can also read this [JavaScript Override Patterns](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/02/javascript-override-patterns.html) to get a better understanding of how to implement inheritance in JavaScript.

Answer (score 15):

For ES5 you will need to use `Object.assign` to copy static methods from BaseClass to SubClass but for ES6 it should work without using `Object.assign`

#### ES5 Example

```js
var BaseClass = function(){

}

BaseClass.sayHi = function(){
   console.log("Hi!");
}

var SubClass = function(){

}

Object.assign(SubClass , BaseClass);

BaseClass.sayHi();   //Hi
SubClass.sayHi(); //Hi
```

#### ES6 Example

```js
class BaseClass {
   static sayHi(){
     console.log("Hi!");
   }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass{

}

BaseClass.sayHi()   //Hi
SubClass.sayHi() //Hi
```

Comment: Of course, technically `Object.assign` is ES6 as well, but you can easily polyfill it or replace it with a loop of assignments.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some transpiled code generated by babel.

Answer (score 9):

After your example code you can do this:

```
for (var i in Class) {
    SomeClass[i] = Class[i];
}
```

to copy static members from `Class` to `SubClass`.

If you're using jQuery, have a look at the [jQuery.Class](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=jQuery.Class) plugin from [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/). Or you can extend John Resig's [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) for a more library-agnostic system.

Comment: I like this answer better because it allows you to customize static methods for some of the children classes OR if you want to have separate static properties for each/some children class.

Answer (score 2):

you can access `static fields` via `this.constructor[staticField]`;

```js
class A {
  static get Foo() { return 'Foo'; }
  
  constructor() {
    console.log(`Class ${this.constructor.name}`, this.constructor.Foo);
  }
}

class B extends A {
    static get Foo() { return 'Baz'; }
}

class C extends A {}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
const c = new C()
```

Comment: functions attached to constructors directly are not inherited unless you attach it to Object prototype directly, but then it's visible to all objects not just children of desired class.

Answer (score 1):

How are you implementing 'static' methods? Since JavaScript doesn't have a native class/instance object model, it all depends on how you've designed your own class system.

If you want to be able to inherit anything it'll have to be using the `SomeClass.prototype` object, rather than putting anything directly on the `SomeClass` constructor function. So essentially you'll be defining static methods as normal instance methods, but ones that don't care about what value of `this` is passed into them.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the base class constructor as the prototype of the derived class one. This is basically the way ES6 does it behind the scenes

```js
function BaseClass() {
    this.a = 1;
}

BaseClass.prototype.b = function() { /** instance */ };
BaseClass.c = function() { console.log("static ") };

function DerivedClass() {
    BaseClass.call(this); // Super constructor call
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(DerivedClass.prototype, BaseClass.prototype); // Instance inheritance
Object.setPrototypeOf(DerivedClass, BaseClass); // Static inheritance

DerivedClass.c() //→ static
```

But notice that, at least when I'm writing this, `BaseClass` does not have `Object` as its prototype, so it does not inherit static methods like `Object.assign()`, it instead has `Function.prototype` as a prototype

```js
class A { }

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(A) === Function.prototype); //→ true
```

This is true unless we explicitly extend `Object`

```js
class A extends Object { }

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(A) === Object); //→ true

console.log(A.assign); //→ function assign() { [native code] }
```