# Should extending a es2015 class copy the properties on the constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Apologies if this seems poorly researched, but I'm having trouble finding any mention of this behavior:

```
class ClassA {...}
ClassA.property = 123;
​
class ClassB extends ClassA {...}
​
ClassB.property //undefined
```

Is there a preferred/idiomatic way to copy these properties to the subclass's constructor?

Edit: As it turns out, this was a premature distillation of the problem which was actually caused by react-css-modules not copying over React-specific properties. A more accurate distillation:

```
class ClassA extends SomeClass {...}
console.log('ClassA', ClassA.defaultProps);
//ClassA Object {propA: ""}
​
console.log('ClassA CSSMod', CSSModules(ClassA, styles).defaultProps);
//ClassA CSSMod undefined
​
ClassA.defaultProps = SomeClass.defaultProps;
console.log('ClassA CssMod after explicit copy', CSSModules(ClassA, styles).defaultProps);
//ClassA CssMod after explicit copy Object {propA: ""}
```

Comment: What babel settings do you use? In pure ES6, `ClassB` *does* prototypically inherit from `ClassA`, and its `.property` should be `123`.

Comment: ES6 classes compile down to the prototype chain, they are nothing more than syntatic sugar. Looking further, the real question boils down to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441508/how-to-inherit-static-methods-from-base-class-in-javascript, and the general consensus there was that you have to do a manual copy, or use a tool that does such.

Comment: @ArcSine: That question you linked only covers ES5. In ES6, `ClassA` is in the prototype chain of `ClassB` without needing to do anything special about it.

Comment: Properties on the constructor, per the question title, are not on the prototype, they are static properties.  They do not inherit because inheritance only happens via the prototype chain. And, ES2015 classes are ES5 functions with prototypes, its just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @ArcSine: Why do you think constructors wouldn't have a prototype chain? Of course, also `A.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `B.prototype`, but as you noticed that's not what this question is about.

Comment: You are right @Bergi, I just ran a simple test, and the constructors do indeed inherit properties from each other. That is odd to me, but I was obviously wrong.

Comment: @Bergi Stage 1 and react-transform. Seems you're right. I may have disingenuously distilled the problem without testing. This may be a React.js thing. I'll get back to you. Sorry folks.