# Inheriting static properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, properties, static

The design pattern I use in my current project is:

```
var MyConstructor = function() { ... };
MyConstructor.STATIC_PROPERTY = 'static';
```

Now if i want to inherit from MyConstructor class, I'd do:

```
var ChildClass = function() { ... };
ChildClass.prototype = new MyConstructor(); // Or Object.create(...)
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
```

Problem is `ChildClass.STATIC_PROPERTY` is undefined / not inherited ...

Is there a way to fix that?

Secondary question:

If I `console.log(MyConstructor)`, I'd get `function() { ...}` and nothing about `MyConstructor.STATIC_PROPERTY` when it's actually there. Where is that `STATIC_PROPERTY` stored in the end? How can I check/display it?

Comment: "Static" properties are simply properties on the constructor function objects. They don't have anything to do with the JavaScript inheritance scheme.

Comment: Try `console.dir(MyConstructor)` to see the static properties.

Comment: Since you have access to `MyConstructor()` in the scope where you define `ChildClass`, something like `ChildClass.STATIC_PROPERTY = MyConstructor.STATIC_PROPERTY` should work. ( but might not be desirable ) As stated, it has nothing to do with prototypal inheritance. Nether is it static without using `Object.defineProperty()` or it's alternatives. We can overwrite it all we want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inherit static methods from base class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441508/how-to-inherit-static-methods-from-base-class-in-javascript)

Comment: "*Or Object.create(...)*" - [it's not exactly optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ES6 `class`, which does prototypically inherit from the parent class (constructor function object):

```js
function MyConstructor() { /* … */ }
MyConstructor.STATIC_PROPERTY = 'static';

class ChildClass extends MyConstructor { /* … */ }
console.log(ChildClass.STATIC_PROPERTY);
```

The alternative would be to either copy all properties (like with `Object.assign`) or to use `Object.setPrototypeOf` on the `ChildClass`.